# Div elements with vertical only scroll bar and auto adjusting width

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am implementing a dynamic menu. The contents are populated based the result of JSON requests. The menu has different levels, each level depends on the choice made at the previous level.

What I would like to achieve is for all the levels of the menu to have the same height, with a vertical scroll bar for those levels where the content would overflow the height. At the same time, I would like the width to be adjusted for the content (no horizontal scroll bar). It is almost working as I want it, except that it seems like the width of the divs is not adjusted for the width of the scroll bar, and the scroll bar ends up hiding the content. As in the image below:

[image: broken menu]

My CSS is as follows:

```
.menu {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: black;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: rgb(200, 230, 255);
 margin: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.menuItem {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: rgb(220, 245, 255);
 margin: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding: 2px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

This behavior is present in Chrome and Firefox, but (perhaps not unexpectedly) not in IE8.
If someone could point out how to achieve the desired effect, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: You're running into a browser implementation issue. Each browser does its 'chrome' bits differently. The only way I can think to deal with it is to add padding to the right of each of those blocks to account for the possible presence of a scroll bar.

Comment: It seems like it's an issue of adding the scroll bar on the inside of the element as opposed to the outside.

Comment: The padding is not a practical solution. I would have to detect which menus have scroll bars, and add padding only for those. Otherwise there will be a lot of unsightly padding all over the place.

Comment: Because the browser decides where and how it puts scrollbars this isn't an issue that is directly controllable by CSS. You need some kind of work around. You might try wrapping each of those columns in a div and apply the scrollbar to the wrapper. Don't know if it will work for you but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Managed to find a work around, see my answer below.

Comment: (Can't answer my own question yet) After much searching and trying different things, the only thing that I could make work for me is to check if the number of entries in the menu is larger than the number of items in the left-most menu (which dictates the height), and if it is, add the width of a scrollbar. How to determine the scrollbar width can be found easily by googling.